# Unable to make responsive navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, navigation

I am making site responsive. I am using the following code to make navigation as select box for mobile devices. But the code is not working. Am I missing something ?

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <!--START: menuitems_view-->
        <!--START: TOP_LINK_FORMAT-->
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
            <a href="infopage.asp?page=[link_id]"
               class="menu" target="[link_target]">
               [link_name]
            </a>
        </td>
        <!--END: TOP_LINK_FORMAT-->
        <!--END: menuitems_view-->
    </tr>
</table>
<select></select>
```

Script code is as follow :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
//Appending Select in NAv for Small Resolutions Devices

// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("#main-nav");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Site Navigation..."
}).appendTo("#main-nav select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("#main-nav a, #main-nav a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("#main-nav select");
});
$("#main-nav select").change(function() {
       window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();}
    );

});

</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: IF your problem is, the menu showing up twice, remove the `<select>` in the HTML or remove `create dropdown base` in script.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am not sure what are you trying to achieve so just writing couple of mistakes I saw.

First the HTML is corrupted nav tag is missing end tag.

The other thing is you already have select tag in the end of the nav tag but you still create your own by jQuery and `.appendTo("#main-nav select")` adds the options both of them. 
If you want only one remove `<select></select>`

Apart from these the creation of options are fine and the change event works.